# @conduitvc/dynamodb-emulator@0.5.3 install error

Tags: node.js, npm

Error while installing @conduitvc/dynamodb-emulator@0.5.3 install with npm

All other npm install runs and is being installed using vscode in a Windows environment.

```
$npm install

> @conduitvc/dynamodb-emulator@0.5.3 install C:\Users\user\Desktop\temp\node_modules\@conduitvc\dynamodb-emulator
> download --extract -o emulator https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/dynamodb_local_latest.zip && ./install.sh
'.'is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
npm WARN @conduitvc/appsync-emulator-serverless@0.14.5 requires a peer of aws-appsync@>= 1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/ascoltatori@4.3.0-patch.2 requires a peer of ioredis@>=2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/ascoltatori@4.3.0-patch.2 requires a peer of msgpack-lite@>=0.1.20 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/ascoltatori@4.3.0-patch.2 requires a peer of zmq@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/ascoltatori@4.3.0-patch.2 requires a peer of zeromq@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/ascoltatori@4.3.0-patch.2 requires a peer of amqp@>=0.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/ascoltatori@4.3.0-patch.2 requires a peer of amqplib@>=0.5.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/ascoltatori@4.3.0-patch.2 requires a peer of mqtt@>=2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/ascoltatori@4.3.0-patch.2 requires a peer of mongodb@>=2.1.18 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/ascoltatori@4.3.0-patch.2 requires a peer of kerberos@~0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/ascoltatori@4.3.0-patch.2 requires a peer of qlobber-fsq@>=6.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/ascoltatori@4.3.0-patch.2 requires a peer of kafka-node@>=0.5.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/mosca@2.8.3-patch.3 requires a peer of leveldown@~1.4.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/mosca@2.8.3-patch.3 requires a peer of amqp@~0.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/mosca@2.8.3-patch.3 requires a peer of ioredis@^1.15.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @conduitvc/mosca@2.8.3-patch.3 requires a peer of mongodb@~2.1.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @graphql-modules/core@0.7.5 requires a peer of graphql@^14.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @graphql-modules/di@0.7.5 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@^0.1.12 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-prettier@3.1.1 requires a peer of eslint@>= 5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-prettier@3.1.1 requires a peer of prettier@>= 1.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-prettier@6.7.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=3.14.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\sane\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @conduitvc/dynamodb-emulator@0.5.3 install: `download --extract -o emulator https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/dynamodb_local_latest.zip && ./install.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @conduitvc/dynamodb-emulator@0.5.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-11T04_01_59_301Z-debug.log
```

I also checked the environment variable.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I'm afraid there's nothing we can do. The installation script for this node module is trying to execute `./install.sh` but Windows does not understand the `.` as a command to execute a file. If you were to install this node module on Linux, it would work because this OS will understand `./` as an attempt to execute `install.sh`, whereas Windows can't do that.

A workaround would be to download all the source code files from their repository and do a manual installation, but as of today I could not find a public repository for this node module.